# Calling c file in android java: fgets() function doesn't working on HTC Desire

Tags: java, android, c, mobile, android-ndk

I have a C code that contains `fgets` function and I call this code from android java.

I run this app on 2 mobiles (Samsung Galaxy & Sony Xperia) and every thing is OK.

But when I run the app on HTC Desire 300 and 500, the app stopped at `fgets` function!!.

This is the command that make the app stopped:

```
line = fgets(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), modem);
```

where: ***{EDIT1}***

```
static char buf[4 * 1024];
FILE *modem;
char *line="AT\r";
char q[4 * 1024 * 10];

modem = fopen("/dev/smd0", "r+b");
if (modem == NULL) 
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "2fopen() failed: /dev/smd0\n");
}

res = fputs(line, modem);
if (res < 0)
{
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ("5failed to send '%s' to modem res = " + res,line)); 
}
line = fgets(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), modem);
```

***EDIT2:***

The error in `logCat` is like that:

```
Tag:     HTCBuildFlagAdpater 
Text:    Fail to get htc sku id by customization
```

What does this problem stands for?
Is there any command that can I use instead of it?

Comment: What are you trying to read? Some specific hardware?

Comment: Where do you open the file? Is it on the external storage? (By the way you should never hardcode `"/sdcard/"` ever.) Are you sure modem variable is not NULL, and initialized?

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I'm trying to read some low level info from the modem of the mobile.

Comment: @Sipka I'll edit the Q. to add the directory. yes I'm sure because the same code is running perfectly on another device as I said in the Q.

Comment: Cannot understand that you can use fputs on a FILE that is opened in read mode.

Comment: @greenapps r+ means: *read/update: Open a file for update (**both for input and output**). The file must exist.* Source from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: fputs: `This function returns a non-negative value else, on error it returns EOF.` from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fputs.htm so it will fail on fputs already.

Comment: Oh sorry i only saw the r and b.

Comment: And now saw that EOF is often implemented as -1. And the link i gave you is a very bad tutorial as return values are neglected.

Comment: The posted code doesn't look like it should crash.  Can you show the debuggerd crash backtrace in the question?

Comment: @fadden I'll edit the Q and add the error

Comment: There is no problem in the code because it ran successfully on 2 different kind of mobile, but I want to know where is the problem? and how can I deal with it?

Comment: The message you added doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the problem.  What exactly do you mean by "app stopped at fgets"?  Is it hung?  Native crash with a stack trace?  If the latter, show the stack trace.  (How do you know it's in `fgets`?)

Comment: @fadden app stopped: showing black screen and getting out from the app. When I run the program without `fgets`, it runs successfully. When I put `fgets`, it doesn't work.

Comment: So... it's blocking on the read() call, waiting for data?

Answer (score 0):

Which observations lead to the conclusion that the application stops at that line?

By "stop," do you mean that the application is hanging at that line, or that the application terminates?

If the former, perhaps it's waiting for input from the device, forever.

If the latter, perhaps there is a bug in their C implementation, but that's less likely than discovering later that the application is not actually terminating at the point in the code that you think it is.